# Unable to compile join stream code with Apache flink | Kinesis Data Analytics

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am not able to compile and run join code in Apache Flink with Kinesis Data Analytics. Following the documentation and with some research my code looks like this:

```
stream_1.join(stream_2)
      .where((x: String) => x.orderId)
        .equalTo((x: String) => x.orderId)
          .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(2)))
          .apply{ (e1, e2) => e1 + "," + e2 }.addSink(createSinkFromStaticConfig())
```

This fails with error: `value orderId is not a member of String`

Since, my raw data is json, I also tried something like:

```
    stream_1.join(stream_2)
      .where((x: String) => jsonParser.readValue(x, classOf[JsonNode]).get("orderId").asText)
        .equalTo((x: String) => jsonParser.readValue(x, classOf[JsonNode]).get("orderId").asText)
          .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(2)))
          .apply{ (e1, e2) => e1 + "," + e2 }.addSink(createSinkFromStaticConfig())
```

which is failing with error:

```
 error: overloaded method value where with alternatives:
[INFO]   [KEY](x$1: org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector[String,KEY], x$2: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[KEY])org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.JoinedStreams[String,String]#Where[KEY] <and>
[INFO]   [KEY](x$1: org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector[String,KEY])org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.JoinedStreams[String,String]#Where[KEY]
[INFO]  cannot be applied to (String => String)
[INFO]       .where((x: String) => jsonParser.readValue(x, classOf[JsonNode]).get("orderId").asText)
```

I am not sure what documentation means by select key in:

```
orangeStream.join(greenStream)
    .where(elem => /* select key */)
    .equalTo(elem => /* select key */)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(2)))
    .apply { (e1, e2) => e1 + "," + e2 }
```

Can anyone help me in how to select the join key from my stream?

More details:

- Source: Kinesis Data Streams
- Stream Type: DataStream[String]

Comment: Hi! You are doing right - the `where` clause accepts mapping function from element to the target value. This might be a lack of type info issue - could you please try adding `implicit val typeInfo = TypeInformation.of(classOf[String])` ? Also, is the `jsonParser` serializable ?

Comment: Please also make sure that you have the following import in your code: `import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.extensions._`.